# how to parse output ANSI code from script file (scriptreplay)

Tags: escape-characters, terminal-emulator, ansi

I'm trying to understand how `script` log file works So I can implement it in [jQuery Terminal](https://terminal.jcubic.pl/) to play script files. I've found this [JavaScript library](https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/scriptreplayjs/src/branch/main/scriptreplay.js). Didn't test it only looked at the code that is pretty simple. It just takes bytes from the timing file and prints the number of the bytes that are in the timing file. And that's it the rest is taken care of by the VT100 emulator.

But I was looking at the file and I don't understand the ANSI codes there.

- `?2004h`
- `?2004l`

This is using the `TERM=vt100` variable like in README, but I would like to support everything that Xterm supports. and It has those codes:

- `]777;notify;Command completed;cat\]777;precmd\]0;`
- `\]7;file://jcubic/home/kuba/projects/jcubic/terminal/test/script`

I don't understand sequence `1B \ 1B`, `1B]7;...` or `1B]777;...` and that extra stuff. Are they documented somewhere?

Comment: 777 is used in some other terminal emulator than xterm (e.g., urxvt which mentions it on a single line of text).  In that case, you can assume that it's not documented.

Comment: ?2004h and ?2004l are xterm's [bracketed-paste](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Bracketed-Paste-Mode) feature.  In that case, `TERM=vt100` is either irrelevant or incorrect, depending on your circumstances.

Comment: @ThomasDickey what about `1B\1B` and `1B]7;`

Comment: Those are fragments which it's hard to say.  Also, you can have keyboard-keys interspersed in the script-recording (and those are only "documented" in the source-code).

Comment: `]7;` looks like a URL escape but I would have expected [that to be `]8;`](https://purpleidea.com/blog/2018/06/29/hyperlinks-in-gnome-terminal/).